# How do i create a new proxy model based on another model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model named tranasaction.

```
class transactions(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    saleduser = models.ForeignKey('UserData',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vclouduser_data', blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,max_digits=20,decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,max_digits=20,decimal_places=2)
```

And I need to create a summary report,
so I create a new Model.

```
class SaleSummary(transactions):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = 'Sale Summary'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Sales Summary'
```

what i need that i need to get the total amount of each type as a new model.

please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not really look like a use case for proxy models. Since if you later want to `.save()` a `SaleSummary`, then what should happen? Nothing? Creating a new row (so doubling the total)?

Comment: i just need to show the model as a report. No need to save the Model

Comment: @Jls: then I think it is not really a (proxy) `model`, you should use. Probably just a class where you attach logic to do the querying, and make it transparent to the user.

Comment: i just write a query to do that. but am getting error ' 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta' transactions.objects.values("type").annotate(totalsales=Sum('amount')).values('type', 'totalsales')

Comment: What if you drop the last `.values()`. Are you sure you did not make an `.aggregate(..)`?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example of a proxy model for a normal model, with a filtering example. I hope it will be helpful for you that how can you create the proxy model and how can you filter specific data from any model for the admin site. You also can apply this for your custom API response, Then you should write this code in serializers. Best of luck.**

> models.py

```
class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    """ 
        Purpose: create a custom auth user table
    """

    name = models.CharField('name of user',max_length=256)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('user creation date', auto_now_add=True)
    
    
    is_admin = models.BooleanField('is a admin', default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('is a staff', default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField('if a superuser', default=False)
    status = models.ForeignKey(SesameUserStatus, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='sesame_user_status_type', default=2)

    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='sesame_user_organization_info', default=1)  

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    

    def has_perm(self,prm,obj=None):
        return self.is_active and self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self,app_level):
        return self.is_active and self.is_admin

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} // {self.email} // {self.organization.name}' 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User"
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['email']),
        ]



class UserProxyModel(UserModel):
    """ 
        Purpose: create proxy model to visualize only pending user
    """

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = "Pending User"
        verbose_name_plural = "Pending Users"
```

###########################################################################

> admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'date_joined', 'is_admin', 'is_staff']   

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel


class UserProxyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'date_joined', 'is_admin', 'is_staff', 'organization', 'status']   

    
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request) 

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs.filter(status=SESAME_USERS["status"]["PENDING"]).order_by('id')  
        return None

    class Meta:
        model = UserProxyModel
        
admin.site.register(UserModel, UserAdmin)  
admin.site.register(UserProxyModel, UserProxyModelAdmin)
```